# Send commands to be executed in the remote host using putty

Tags: putty

I have to run a bunch of commands for a process. I am able to call and login to Putty using the command below and want to be able to execute tar and other things.

I call putty using the following

```
"C:\Users\PSingh69\Desktop\putty.exe -ssh"&" "&UserName & "@10.177.104.109 -pw" &" "&Passwrd
```

Commands to send to the remote host using Putty:

```
cd /psingh69/home/                                                    
tar -cvf /psingh69/home/inbox/myfile.tar ./home/inputfiles/myfile.txt 
tar -tvf /psingh69/home/inbox/myfile.tar                              
cd /psingh69/home/destfolder/inbox/                                   
chmod 777 /psingh69/home/destfolder/inbox/myfile.tar
```

I am able to login to Putty using above command, but I am not sure of how to make the remote host run the above lines.

Comment: Whatever you are hoping to accomplish **`chmod 777` is *wrong* and *dangerous.*** You should switch back to sane permissions ASAP (probably 755 for your particular user case). If you did this on a production system, at a minimum check whether an intruder could have abused this security flaw; in the worst case, reinstall the system from scratch from known-good backups.

Comment: This question already exist in SU https://superuser.com/q/587629/235569

Answer (score 1):

Most versions of Putty allow you to specify a "remote command file" using the `-m` command-line switch. Add your commands to a text file and pass it as a parameter to your `putty.exe` command:

```
> putty.exe ... -m "c:\mycommands.sh"
```

Note that you'll need to escape your quotes (by doubling them) when used in a VBScript string literal:

```
pcmd = "putty.exe -m ""c:\mycommands.sh"""
```

Comment: The tar file name is not fixed, I have to take that one from user. Isn't there a way to put these commands in my vbs script itself rather than calling another script ?

Comment: You could create the command file using VBScript (`CreateTextFile()`) so that you can write dynamic values to it. Then, pass it to Putty as shown above.